# Openssl Client Certificates

Tags: ssl, openssl, x509, mutual-authentication, pkix

I'm trying to create a basic SSL socket using self signed certificates. I'm following Ubuntu's guide at [OpenSSL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSSL). I have a working `server_crt.pem` and `server_key.pem`. When I place the `server_crt.pem` in my client (as well as having it in my server) the SSL socket works.

However I know that clients should have their own certificates and not have duplicates of the server. I've looked for duplicates and haven't found any straight answers to this...

How do I create a client certificate that's linked to my self signed CA file?

Comment: I don't know how hard you've looked but using a search engine and search for [create client certificate](https://www.google.com/search?q=create+client+certificate) results in lots of useful hits which answer your question.

Comment: @ronaldmurphy - The cited duplicate should well on your path since it gives you both the `s_client` commands and the API calls. Come back if you have specific questions. Also see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639)

Comment: @jww how is this in anyway a duplicate? The question you've linked relates to testing using s_server and s_client.. not about creating the certificate?
Please explain

Comment: @ronaldmurphy - Creating certificates is off-topic for Stack Overflow. There is information on Stack Overflow with respect to creating them, but they came from a time when the site's rules were different. A couple of them have been cited for you. The cited duplicate provides you with the information you need to use them in your program, and test them using openssl commands. I can remove the duplucate close and move to an off-topic close if you'd like. I find the duplicate close more helpful to the person asking the question.